# Does Stat based Felonies include what is added by equipment

Tags: disgaea-2

looking over the list of Felonies and their conditions for Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days there are a bunch who's conditions are like HP 500+, DEF 200+ etc

i am wondering if the conditions of these Felonies also include the stats that are added by equipment or if the conditions relate only to a character's base stats (with no equipment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stat based felonies which have a condition where a stat must be above a certain level also include what is added to your stats via equipment

after getting Pram who was ta level 100 using Pleinair (also level 100 but didn't have to fight her) i got a particular powerful muscle which boosted by HP +200, at the start of a new game it's kinda hard to tell if the reason why you get a Felony was because your character's base stats met the condition when they leveled up of it was there base stats + equipment which did it the muscle helped out as the moment i nudged over 500 HP i was able to get the felony so since the muscle add 200 HP it would mean by base stats was just over 300 and the condition (according to the wiki) says i need 500 hp